# Not connecting to firebird database remotely

Tags: vb.net, telerik, firebird

I am using Firebird database for my project. Its working on localhost. But when I try to connect to remote server, its gives error "Unable to reach database server on host". Database installed on server and working. My connectionstring is in this format

```
Dim connectionString As String = "character set=UTF8;data source=" & server & ";Port=3050;initial catalog=" & path & ";user id=" & username & ";password=" & password & ";role=" & role
```

When server is localhost its works, but when provide ip of server, then its gives error.
Is there any work to do on server side to allow connect from remote or open port? etc 
Please help how to solve this solution. Thanks

Comment: Can you connect to the database server with - for example - flamerobin? Is there a firewall on the client or the server that might block the connection?

Comment: Yes, port was blocked on server side. By opening it resolves the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Port was blocked on server side. By opening port problem solved. Thanks for all friends.